# if you put an array of characters into a string will there be any errors

Tags: java

Im just going to be upfront about this being for homework but I currently am not able to download java and check but **will the code bellow cause any conversion errors?**

```
char sentence[] = { 'H', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u'};
String output = "The sentence is: ";

for(int i = 0; 1 < sentence.length; i++)
  output+= sentence[i]; 

System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would just be simpler to do this

```java
char sentence[] = { 'H', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u'};
System.out.println("The sentence is: " + String.copyValueOf(sentence));
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem your code has is in this line:
for(int i = 0; ***1*** < sentence.length; i++)
it should be:
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++)
other than that it will print your string follow by the "how are you"

Answer (score 0):

I have just opened jshell.

```
jshell> String c = "cat"
c ==> "cat"

jshell> c += 's'
$3 ==> "cats"
```

In Java, if you concatenate an object, that object's toString method is called.  If you concatenate a primitive, it is automatically converted to a String.

```
jshell> ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
al ==> []

jshell> al.add(4);
$5 ==> true

jshell> al.add(5)
$6 ==> true

jshell> c += al
$7 ==> "cats[4, 5]"
```

Your code should compile as is.

Comment: This is not what "lazy evaluation" means; this is called type coercion.